# how to find real cause when getting "Native Packager exception occurred"

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10

I am trying to build a blackberry10 cordova (v3.2.0) project for the first time. It seems that whenever anything goes wrong I get this generic error:

`[Error: An error occurred while building the blackberry10 project.[ERROR]   Native Packager exception occurred
[ERROR]   Native Packager exception occurred
An error has occurred
]`

I know, that is very nice. After lots of searching around I found some issues in my `config.xml` and fix them. But now I have no clue what else could be worng. Does anyone know how I can get a proper error message about what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turn out the issue in our case was with the [blackberry app description](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/beta/description_element.html) being too long.

To get more information from the native packages run cordova build with the `-d` option.

`cordova build -d`

Hope this helps someone.